# one aspnet webapi controller with two get methods and getting Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

When calling

```
http://mysite.com/Project/42
```

for the routing and methods below I get a "Multiple actions were found that match the request...Get(Int32)...Children(Int32)"

while calling

```
http://mysite.com/Project/42/Children
```

returns correctly.

My routing is:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ForChildren",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/Children",
    defaults: new { action = "Children" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And my methods:

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController {

    public IEnumerable<Project> Get(int id){
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Children(int id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I thought not specifying the action would result in Webapi defaulting to the method (GET). Now it looks like Webapi is running through the methods disregarding their names, only looking for parameter match. I really don't believe that and think I fault elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior/issue with how action selection currently works in Web API. In the scenario where your request is 'http://mysite.com/Project/42', the request matches the 'DefaultApi' route and during action selection the action selector does not have the value for the require variable 'action' and hence it tries to figure out from the list of available actions which can be reached through GET method. It tries to find out the best action from the se based on route parameters (like 'id' here) and query string parameters. In your scenario, the action selector sees 2 get actions each accepting id parameter and hence it sees ambiguity in selecting them.

There is an issue currently filed here which is similar to your scenario:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this is to have only one route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction"  }
);
```

Then decorate your default action:

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController {

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Get(){
        // api/project
        // Return all projects
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Children(int id) {
        // api/project/1/children 
        // Return children of project with id == 1
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to 'rename' Get to "DefaultAction". Instead I set [..., action="Get"}] in the route.  Your answer solved my problem temporarily but @Kiran Challa shone the light on the very base problem. Thx both.

Comment: If you want to mix verb based with traditional routing in on controller, you need to decorate with "DefaultAction". With this approach you do not need to add new routes.

Answer (score 0):

In Web API 2 you can use attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("Project")]
public class ProjectController : ApiController {

    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Get(int id){
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/Children")]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Children(int id) {
        ...
    }
}
```